# Sending an AJAX request in jQuery, getting valid request back but AJAX is throwing an error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX request in jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://someurl.stuff.com",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Host",null);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method",null)
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Origin",null)
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers",null)
      xhr.setRequestHeader("DNT",null)
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding",null)


    },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success")
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
    debugger;
    console.log("failure")
     alert(data)
    }
});
```

I've verified that I am getting a valid JSON back. However, for some reason I am still getting into 'error' above. Can anyone help me with how to bypass that or how I can access the JSON in the result? JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "ins": "first Value", 
  "nx": "second value"
}
```

Edit, so I noticed in the console I get the following message:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What I find strange is that I see the response in Chrome 'Network' tab, I just can't get it to appear within the browser.

Comment: Can you try and change the `dataType` value from 'text json' to only 'json'?

Comment: @Catalyst, no good, I actually had that initially but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out what is happening. Because the response does not contain an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, Chrome's built in security is preventing the JSON from reaching the actual script, although it does reach the server. Works in older IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

If that error callback function is being triggered it's only because your server/backend/url (http://someurl.stuff.com ) is not responding with a 200/2XX status code for that request.

Check this for more information about HTTP Status codes:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors

Comment: Its coming back with an HTTP 200.

Comment: Did you try by removing the beforeSend function ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with the headers but I'd suggest you do some reading on CORS. [This](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) is a pretty good resource. If you wanted to limit who can access your endpoint you could set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://someurl.stuff.com`

```
    $.ajax({
     url: "http://someurl.stuff.com",
     type: 'GET', 
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
       console.log("Success")
       console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(xhr){
      console.log("failure")
      console.log("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
     }
    })
```